# z-index of nested div

Tags: html, css

I have the following **HTML structure**:

```
<div>
    <div class="expandable">
        <div class="custom-select"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="expandable">
        <div class="custom-select"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="choice-select">
        <div class="custom-select"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- "expandable" divs are repeated.
- "custom-select" divs become visible
  on click.
- "choice-select" is at the bottom of all expandable divs and
  contains another select dropdown with a button

**with the following styles**:

```
.expandable {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
.custom-select {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

My problem is this:

- The "custom-select" is used everywhere and has a very high z-index of 9999. Even if multiple of these are used in the same div, the clicked (expanded) one is still visible over the rest of the divs and selects as its in the same parent div.
- I gave "expandable" div a z-index of 10 so that when the "custom-select" is clicked and it overlaps "choice-select", it is still visible and clickable.
- However, since the "expandable" divs all have the same z-index and there can be N number of "expandable" divs, a "custom-select" when clicked and if it happens to expand into the sibling "expandable" div gets cut. Its hidden behind the content of the next "expandable" div.

What do I need to do to ensure that the "custom-select" is always visible? I also tried by giving "expandable" div an opacity of 0.99, but it didn't work. Any tips?

Somewhat indicative code: https://codepen.io/imgr8/pen/bzOrbY

Comment: Do you have any position set on `.choice-select` other than `static`?

Comment: No. And there is no z-index set either. Thats why when I the custom-select from "expandable" div overlays over "choice-select", there is no issue clicking on the list-items from custom-select as its defaulting to auto/0.

Comment: Then, `.custom-select` should be always on top due to its higher z-index base on the html/css you posted.

Comment: But it isn't. I added wrapping divs to the "expandable" containers. Do they matter? Does the fact that the z-index of expandable containers is same change the calculation of the z-index of its child elements -> "custom-select"?

Comment: As long as the wrappers of `.custom-select` doesn't have any position relative/fixed/absolute set it doesn't matter.

Comment: k I did have "position:relative" for the parent of "custom-select" and when I remove it, ti works. But then the css looks really wonky. But I think thats fixable. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you include more source code relevant to the question? The source you provided does not reproduce what you described

Comment: Because absolute child needs a relative parent, try giving that parent a higher z-index than 10 and keep the relative position.

Comment: k updating the html with more details

Comment: https://codepen.io/imgr8/pen/bzOrbY

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question. I just added the z-index on the sibling parent only during hover. That solved it. Thank you for all your help!